# passenger-status - ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, phusion-passenger

My server is:

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.11 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Aug 16 2010 17:44:11
```

My ruby version `ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25 revision 30365) [x86_64-linux]`.

I've installed `passenger 3.0.7` via RubyGems. I've run `passenger-install-apache2-module` and everything went fine. I've modified configuration (load module, edit virtualhost etc.) and restarted Apache. Module is loading fine (apache does not complain). But Passenger is obviously not working:

```
sudo passenger-status
ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running.
```

How can I get it working ?

***Edit 1:***

**/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/passenger.load**

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.7/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
```

Root of passenger:

```
passenger-config --root
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.7
```

Apache VirtualHost sub URI configuration in **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/railsapps**:

```
<VirtualHost <IP ADDRESS>:80>                                                                                                                                                                                    
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName my.server.name

    PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.7
    PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby
    RailsEnv development

    DocumentRoot /www/vhosts/railsapps

    <Directory /www/vhosts/railsapps>
        Options FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    RailsBaseURI /siteA
    <Directory /www/vhosts/railsapps/siteA>
        Options -MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    RailsBaseURI /siteB
    <Directory /www/vhosts/railsapps/siteB>
        AllowOverride All
        Options -MultiViews
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    LogLevel info

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/railsapps_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/railsapps_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Of course as in 'users guide apache.html' `siteA` and `siteB` are symlinks to `siteA/public` and `siteB/public` absolute paths respectively.

***Edit 2:***

In logs there is nothing related to passenger. Permissions are also fine (read and executable) on directories in paths. Even if it was some misconfiguration or permission problem isn't passenger suppose to be running? I mean `sudo passenger-status` should at least output `--- general information ---`. When I place some test html file in `railsapps` directory it is served fine.

**/var/log/apache2/railsapps_error.log**

```
[Sun Jun 19 12:19:08 2011] [error] [client <IP>] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /www/vhosts/railsapps/siteA/
[Sun Jun 19 12:19:08 2011] [error] [client <IP>] File does not exist: /www/vhosts/railsapps/favicon.ico
```

Comment: Can you show your vhost and module definition as well?  They matter for figuring out what's wrong here.

Comment: Of course. I've updated my question.

Comment: Anything in apache error.log?

Comment: No, nothing related to passenger. I've updated my question, though.

Comment: Do you have Passenger mentioned in server string? Check error.log around time of apache restart. Also, check if passenger module loaded at all with `apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_MODULES`.

Comment: I've found it! Thanks to your comment. I was blind before. The log entry was about unable to start watchdog because its executable path does not exist. The one of many sites had PassengerRoot set to old path and old version of passenger. And that was causing a problem. Thank you!

Comment: @CasualCoder Please add your solution as an answer, so that the question appears resolved to others and doesn't keep coming back. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelHampton ok, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log entry was about unable to start watchdog because its executable path does not exist. The one of many sites had PassengerRoot set to old path and old version of passenger. And that was causing a problem.

Comment: How was it fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `passenger-memory-stats` to get some information:

```
$: sudo passenger-memory-stats
```

To use `passenger-status`, you may need to install rvm, then you can:

```
$: rvmsudo passenger-status
```